# GeoServer WMTS- GetCapabilities request Filter

Tags: geoserver, performance, wmts, geowebcache, getcapabilities

We have 100 + GeoTIFF layers which we have to display in the front end via OpenLayers. We use WMTS protocol to fetch data. The initial request "hostname/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities" takes huge time to load (25 Seconds). We tried with Geo web cache still the performance is not good. How to add filters to the GetCapabilities request instead of loading all 100+ GeoTIFF information load only few layers.

We tried with WMS but we want to go with WMTS.

Comment: did you compute overviews for the GeoTIFFs? this typically speeds up the rendering a lot

Comment: @JakobMiksch do you have any reference for this computing? I tried about cloud optimized Tiff but that is more for S3 , we are going with Azure

Comment: To compute overviews you can use GDAL: ‘gdaladdo -r average input.tif’ This should help independent of your cloud hosting provider. Also COG is independent of a cloud hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of virtual service end-points (see the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/configuration/virtual-services.html)) so that rather than requesting all the layers via `http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.21.0/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities` you can ask for all the layers in a workspace with `http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.21.0/topp/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities`

Comment: We using GeoWebCache still the Get capbilities request is not very performant. We tried external cache with middleware ,but is there any configurations which can give better performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Options for reducing the size of the WMTS GetCapabilities response through a request are limited.  Looking at the [1.0.0 specification](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=35326), the best you can do is ask for sections; that still means you get all the layers though.